# primefaces update fails on one page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm sure that the question is asked before, but I can't fin my explicit problem, I'm afraid it is only a little typo and I can't see it.

I have a simple page in primefaces 10 with a toolbar, with an add-button, a table and a dialoge for adding the data. The dialog has a rendered tag that the requiered field are only rendered if there is a new variable. Everything I used on several other pages of my project.

The new Variable is initialized perfectly but the inside of the dialog isn't rendered, if I remove the rendered tag the field is rendered, but I have put some test-content into my new Variable and this isn't shown either, so I think that my update doesn't get called but I don't see why.

So here is my code:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="header">
        <div id="header">
            ChangeLog
        </div>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="main">
        <h:form id="changelogfrm">
            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
            <div class="card">
                <p:toolbar>
                    <p:toolbarGroup>
                        <p:commandButton value="Neu" icon="pi pi-plus" actionListener="#{changeloghandler.newChangelog}"
                                         update=":changelogfrm:manage-change-content" oncomplete="PF('manageChangeDialog').show()"
                                         styleClass="ui-button-success" style="margin-right: .5rem" />
                    </p:toolbarGroup>
                </p:toolbar>
                <p:dataTable var="change" value="#{changeloghandler.changeLogs}"
                    showGridlines="true" size="small" id="dtChange">
                    <p:column headerText="Version">
                        <h:outputText value="#{change.version}" />
                    </p:column>
        
                    <p:column headerText="Typ">
                        <h:outputText value="#{change.changeType}"/>
                    </p:column>
        
                    <p:column headerText="Beschreibung">
                        <h:outputText value="#{change.description}"/>
                    </p:column>
        
                    <p:column headerText="Datum">
                        <h:outputText value="#{change.date}">
                            <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"/>
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                
                <p:dialog header="Change" showEffect="fade" modal="true"
                          widgetVar="manageChangeDialog" responsive="true">
                    <p:outputPanel id="manage-change-content" class="ui-fluid">
                        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty changeloghandler.selected}">
                            <div class="p-field">
                                <p:outputLabel for="chBeschreibung">Beschreibung</p:outputLabel>
                                <p:inputTextarea id="chBeschreibung" value="#{changeloghandler.selected.description}" required="true"/>
                            </div>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:outputPanel>
        
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="pi pi-check" actionListener="#{changeloghandler.save}"
                                         update="manage-change-content" process="manage-change-content @this"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" icon="pi pi-times" onclick="PF('manageChangeDialog').hide()"
                                         class="ui-button-secondary"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dialog>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The save-function in the dialog isn't called either.

I've also checked the html on the site, there is no double-form and the ids are set correctly.

Hope you can help me.

**!!!EDIT!!!**

Hi, here you have the Bean-Class:

```
package main.java.handler;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;

import main.java.persistence.entities.ChangeLog;
import main.java.persistence.entities.enums.ChangeType;
import main.java.persistence.entities.enums.Version;
import main.java.persistence.interfaces.ChangeLogDbInterface;

@Named("changeloghandler")
@SessionScoped
public class ChangeLogHandler implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<ChangeLog> changeLogs;
    private ChangeLog selected;
    private List<Version> versions;
    private ChangeType[] changeTypes;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        changeLogs = ChangeLogDbInterface.loadChangeLogItems();
        versions = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Version v : Version.values()) {
            if(v.isActive()) versions.add(v);
        }
        changeTypes = ChangeType.values();
    }

    public void newChangelog() {
        ChangeLog newLog = new ChangeLog();
        newLog.setDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        this.selected = newLog;
    }
    
    public void save() {
        if (this.selected.getId() == 0) {
            ChangeLogDbInterface.createChangeLogItem(selected);
            this.changeLogs.add(this.selected);
        }
        else {
            ChangeLogDbInterface.updateChangeLogItem(selected);
        }

        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('manageChangeDialog').hide()");
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("changelogfrm:dtChange");
    }
    
    public List<ChangeLog> getChangeLogs() { return changeLogs; }
    public ChangeLog getSelected() { return selected; }
    public List<Version> getVersions() { return versions; }
    public ChangeType[] getChangeTypes() { return changeTypes; }

    public void setChangeLogs(List<ChangeLog> changeLogs) { this.changeLogs = changeLogs; }
    public void setSelected(ChangeLog selected) { this.selected = selected; }
    public void setVersions(List<Version> versions) { this.versions = versions; }
    public void setChangeTypes(ChangeType[] changeTypes) { this.changeTypes = changeTypes; }
}
```

**!!! EDIT 2 !!!**

Here is the template, but I think that doesn't help much either:

```
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Asset Tool Connector</title>
        <link type="text/css"
            href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/style.css"
            rel="stylesheet" />
        <link type="image/x-icon"
            href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/netzwerk.png"
            rel="shortcut icon" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="header"/>
        <f:event listener="#{sessionHandler.checkLoggedIn}" type="preRenderView" />
        <div id="menu">
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
        </div>
    
        <div id="main">
            <ui:insert name="main"/>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div>
                <h:form id="footerForm">
                    <p:commandButton value="ChangeLog" action="/changelog?faces-redirect=true"/>
                </h:form>
            </div>
            &#169; ATC - by 5332
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Except the button in the footer links to the page with my issue, if that would be an issue.

Comment: I would prefer to create a form for the table and one for the dialog, anyway, can you add `changeloghandler` class code? Or write when `changeloghandler.selected` is set?

Comment: Hi, added the Bean the selected var is initialized wenn you click onthe add-button. I do it in this way on some other sites and it was never a problem.

Comment: I tried your code, without the template and trying to figure out other beans and it works fine, so I suggest checking without the template or please post that code. As the last suggestion, you can try to separate that page into two forms, one for the data table and one within the dialog.

Comment: Hi, I've added the template and now I try your suggestion with the double form.

Comment: Hi, don't know why, but splitting the forms did the job. Thanks for the help, but could you explain why it worked?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but if your table has a lot of rows (since it has only few columns) the button that processes everything in the form, so also the data table, can reach MAX_POST_SIZE or max number of parameters for HTTP post request. In these cases, you should see some errors, somewhere, so if you don't see them it could be something else.